# Dynamically change php ini variable

Tags: php

I have recently purchase Godaddy Linux Shared hosting. In My site there is one php.ini file in my root(/) directory. As my requirement i have set ini paramete **output_buffering=on** but it will not take effect in my site.
because after changing ini setting we need to restart server, but as it is godaddy's shared server they are not able to restart server. I have talked also in support. But no result.
so can any one give solution how can php.ini change will take effect without restart apache server.

I have tried by setting in .htacces as **php_value output_buffering on** but it won't work.

Comment: well they are one of the worst hosts

Comment: Why do you need output buffering on?  If you have a legitimate use case, generally you can do your own output buffering. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use ini_set(). https://www.php.net/ini_set

```
ini_set('output_buffering', 'on');
```

Of course this is not completely ideal, as you have to call it wherever you want output buffering to be enabled.

Comment: Actually there is on header already sent error occurs in my site. i know there is blank space anywhere in code so but i am not able to detect it. so after set the buffer on it will omit the space in php tag.

Comment: You should try to solve this problem by editing the code which prints the blank spaces.